# c# custom Dictionary get StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

i made a custom Dictionary

but when i try to set some value i got error

```
StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
```

i dont get error on getter only the setter

let me share my code

```
 public class myClass : Dictionary<object, object>
 {
    public myClass () { }
    public myClass (int x) { }

    public object this[object key] { get { return this[key]; } set { this[key] = value; } }

    public object Clone() {
      return  new Dictionary<object, object>(this);
    }
    public IEnumerator<DictionaryEntry> GetEnumerator() {
      return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
    
 }
```

data i tried to set to my class

```
        myClass   properties = new myClass ();
        properties ["235"] = "www";
```

i don't see any StackOverflowException in the setter how did this value make StackOverflow?

Comment: Your indexer is recursive. You reference `this[key]` from `this[key]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
 public object this[object key] { get { return this[key]; } set { this[key] = value; } }
```

This cause an infinite recursion since the indexer is calling itself.
If you're going to inherit from a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you should change it to

```
 public object this[object key] { get { return base[key]; } set { base[key] = value; } }
```

Having said that, inheriting from a Dictionary is kinda like inheriting from List - which means [it's probably a bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: (this)  refer to the setter not to the Dictionary it self?

Comment: c# is not javascript. `this` always refers to he containing type.